# How to call a batch file that is one level up from the current batch file directory?

Tags: batch-file, call

I'm using a batch file in `folder1\folder2\file.bat`.

There is a batch file in parent folder `folder1` that I want to open through `file.bat`.

I have tried using:

```
start ..\..\code.bat
```

But this results in an error message because the file couldn't be found.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could just:

```
cd..
start Code.bat
```

And that would start code.bat from its own directory

Comment: that is not what been asked. there might be a reason why you want to run it from child directory. for example because you need to pass some files from child directory as arguments.

Answer (score 28):

I want to explain better what should be used with an example as the answers posted up to now work only with current working directory being the directory containing the batch file `file.bat`.

There is a directory structure as follows:

- **C:\**

  - **Temp**

    - **Folder 1**

      - **Folder 2**

        - *Example.bat*
      - *Parent.bat*

The current working directory is **C:\Temp** on executing `Example.bat` either with

```
"Folder 1\Folder 2\Example.bat"
```

or with

```
"C:\Temp\Folder 1\Folder 2\Example.bat"
```

The batch file `Parent.bat` contains for example:

```
echo %0 is active.
pause
```

The batch file `Example.bat` contains already:

```
@echo off
echo Calling Parent.bat ...
rem How to run Parent.bat here?
echo %0 is active.
pause
```

The really working solutions in this scenario with the current working directory being a different directory than directory containing `Example.bat` are as follows.

---

### Continue batch processing with *Parent.bat*

```
"%~dp0..\Parent.bat"
```

`%0` references argument 0 on execution of the batch file which is always the name of the batch file as specified in parent process on starting the batch file.

But wanted is the drive and path of the batch file without double quotes. Therefore the expression `%~dp0` is used to get **C:\Temp\Folder 1\Folder 2\** from argument 0.

On this path the string **..\Parent.bat** is appended, and additionally the entire new file name
**C:\Temp\Folder 1\Folder 2\..\Parent.bat** is enclosed in double quotes because of the spaces.

There is no return to `Example.bat` after processing of `Parent.bat` finished.

---

### Call *Parent.bat* like a subroutine

```
call "%~dp0..\Parent.bat"
```

Command **call** results in execution of batch file `Parent.bat` in same command process (console window) with halting the execution of `Example.bat` until `Parent.bat` finished.

The batch execution continues on next line in `Example.bat` after processing of `Parent.bat` finished.

**Exception:**
`Parent.bat` contains command `exit` without switch `/B` because this results in an immediate exit of command line interpreter `cmd.exe` processing `Example.bat` and `Parent.bat`.

Execute `call /?` or `help call` in a command prompt window for short help on command **call**.

---

### Start *Parent.bat* as parallel process

```
start "Parent Batch" "%~dp0..\Parent.bat"
```

Command **start** without any parameter with the exception of the optional title results in execution of batch file `Parent.bat` by a separate command process in a separate console window without halting the execution of `Example.bat`.

Therefore both batch files run at same time (more or less).

**Note:**
Command **start** interprets first string in double quotes as title. Therefore it is necessary to define explicitly a title in double quotes when the batch file or application to start, or any argument of the started batch file / application must be specified in double quotes because of 1 or more spaces.

Execute `start /?` or `help start` in a command prompt window for short help on command **start**.

---

### Call *Parent.bat* as separate process

```
start "Parent Batch" /wait "%~dp0..\Parent.bat"
```

Command **start** with optional parameter `/wait` results in execution of the started batch file / application as separate process (additional console window for a batch file or console application), but halting the execution of the current batch file until the started process (Windows application or batch file / console application executed in a new console window) terminates itself.

Answer (score 18):

`..\` is used to go one level up. your case requires two levels up
Try:

```
start ..\..\code.bat
```

Comment: In his case, he only need one level up, or that is what he asked, if you read his post, that is the exact thing he tried.
For bat files you need to use call instead of start (at least if you want to ontinue in the original bat file after the second one finishes):
So the correct way would be:
call ..\code.bat

Answer (score 3):

try to use this:

```
start ../code.bat
```