# batch code reads file names and runs them

Tags: batch-file

how can batch read file names and run them in loop.

I would have a file with file names and run them within a batch.

File names would be.

```
user1
user2
user3
```

And their location would be

```
C:\User\Desktop\user1.exe
C:\User\Desktop\user2.exe
C:\User\Desktop\user3.exe
```

If all can be done without input file that would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

The code to use without a list file is:

```
for %%I in ("%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\*.exe") do "%%~fI"
```

The code to use with a list file is:

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("File with the file names.txt") do "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%%I.exe"
```

The path can be whatever is wanted. Here is specified the desktop folder of the current user.

For understanding the used command **FOR** and how it works, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands and read entirely all help pages displayed for the command very carefully.

- `for /?`

You might be also interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24725044/3074564) explaining the 4 methods to start or call an application.