# Cannot run python server using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Here are the commands in batch:

```
D:
cd D:\Startup\venv\Scripts
activate
cd D:\Startup\
python manage.py runserver
```

Commands after "activate" are not executed for some reasons. I tried to put "cmd /k activate" instead "activate" but result is still the same except the command line is still open. What is wrong here

Comment: I've no clue what `activate` is and what it does.

Comment: @Falko it launches python environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose `activate` is a batch file and therefore needed is:

```
cd /D D:\Startup\venv\Scripts
call activate.bat
cd D:\Startup
python.exe manage.py runserver
```

Without command **call** the processing of a batch file continues on other batch file without returning which is the reason why the last two lines where never executed. Run in a command prompt window `call /?`  and read output help and for more details see for example also answer on [How to call a batch file in the parent folder of current batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24725044/3074564)

Command **CD** with parameter `/D` makes it possible to change directory and drive at the same time as `cd /?` executed in a command prompt window explains.

In batch files it is advisable to specify batch files and executables with file extension.

Comment: thank you @Mofi , this is what I've been looking for