# Command runs in commandline but not through BAT file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am running the following command in cmd for which I am able to get the log successfully.

cd C:\Users\sriram\AppData\Local\Temp\license1.1.4

C:\Users\sriram\AppData\Local\Temp\license1.1.4>lsmon.exe testprovilic.muc.company> C:\Users\sriram\AppData\Local\Temp\license1.1.4\usage.log

Above command will generate the logs in the usage log file. But I created a batch file as below for which it is giving me an error testprovilic.muc.company not found

@ECHO off

SET variable=C:\Users\s.d.vaidyanathan\AppData\Local\Temp\usage.log

START "C:\Users\s.d.vaidyanathan\AppData\Local\Temp\license1.1.4"lsmon.exe testprovilic.muc.company> "%variable%"

Could you please help me solve this issue.

Thanks and Regards,
Sriram

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the "cd C:\Users\sriram\AppData\Local\Temp\license1.1.4" to the batch file.  Or use the full path to the file like:

```
C:\Users\sriram\AppData\Local\Temp\license1.1.4\testprovilic.muc.company
```

So you would have ..

```
@ECHO off
cd C:\Users\sriram\AppData\Local\Temp\license1.1.4
SET variable=C:\Users\s.d.vaidyanathan\AppData\Local\Temp\usage.log
START "C:\Users\s.d.vaidyanathan\AppData\Local\Temp\license1.1.4"lsmon.exe testprovilic.muc.company> "%variable%"
```

or you could

```
@ECHO off
SET variable=C:\Users\s.d.vaidyanathan\AppData\Local\Temp\usage.log
START "C:\Users\s.d.vaidyanathan\AppData\Local\Temp\license1.1.4"lsmon.exe C:\Users\sriram\AppData\Local\Temp\license1.1.4\testprovilic.muc.company> "%variable%"
```

Comment: Hello @LuvnJesus,
I tried with cd as well I am getting the same error. actually testprovilic.muc.company is the server which I am passing to the lsmon.exe. Is there any specific format to pass it through bat file?

Comment: Why is lsmon.exe outside the quotes and why is there no slash between the path and lsmon.exe?

Comment: @CareyGregory I make that folder as the default and and then I try to run exe whicn is present inside that folder.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work:

```
"C:\Users\s.d.vaidyanathan\AppData\Local\Temp\license1.1.4"lsmon.exe
```

The whole path needs to be in quotes and there needs to be a backslash after the last folder name.

Change it to this:

```
"C:\Users\s.d.vaidyanathan\AppData\Local\Temp\license1.1.4\lsmon.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

Open a command prompt window, type `set` and press key <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to run this command. You get displayed all predefined environment variables with their current values. You can see **TEMP**, **USERPROFILE** and **USERNAME**.

Windows command line has a help. The command to get help is `help`, yes really. Try it out! You need help on command **CD**, enter in command prompt window `help cd` or alternatively `cd /?`. You need help on command **SET** and **START**, run `help set` or `set /?` and `help start` or `start /?`. All internal commands of `cmd.exe` and nearly all console applications support the parameter `/?` and output 1 or more help pages on running the command with this parameter.

You need a better overview of standard Windows commands? See Microsoft's [command-line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) and SS64's [command line reference](https://ss64.com/nt/).

I assume that `sriram` is your user account and `s.d.vaidyanathan` is the user account of someone else. By default a standard user has no permissions to access folders and files in a different user's profile than the own profile since Windows Vista. That means, you logged in as `sriram` can't access the files and folders of `C:\Users\s.d.vaidyanathan` because of missing permissions to do so. It would be necessary to use command [Runas](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) to run the batch file with account `s.d.vaidyanathan`.

```
@echo off

rem Execute lsmon.exe from license1.1.4 in my folder for temporary
rem files and folders and write the log file also into this folder.

"%TEMP%\license1.1.4\lsmon.exe" testprovilic.muc.company >"%TEMP%\license1.1.4\usage.log"
```

**Note:** Double quotes must be used around path AND file name. Just double quoting parts of a file name with path may or may not work depending on error correction and how the application is written. For details see answer on [set environment variables with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402887/3074564).

See also the Microsoft article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

And regarding right usage of command **START** not really needed here see for example answer on [How to call a batch file in the parent folder of current batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24725044/3074564)