# How to start a windows batch file with variables from another batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have tried the following:

```
set SOME_PATH="C:\some_path"
start "some program" %SOME_PATH%\pathToScript\anotherBatch.bat %SOME_PATH%\pathToConfig\some.properties
```

My aim is to start `"anotherBatch.bat"` which takes the path to a config file as an argument: `%SOME_PATH%\pathToConfig\some.properties`

Unfortunatley, I got an error in the new command prompt that my syntax for the file name is incorrect.

What is the right syntax for the start command above?

Comment: I suggest to read answer on [How to call a batch file that is one level up from the current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24725044/3074564) explaining four methods to run a batch file from within a batch file. You should embed each argument string in double quotes in case of any argument string contains a space or one of the characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~<|>``. The first double quote on assigning the path to environment variable `SOME_PATH` is also positioned wrong, see [How to set environment variables with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402887/3074564)

Answer (score 2):

You should `Call` a batch file instead of `Start` one.

```bat
Set "SOME_PATH=C:\some_path"
Call "%SOME_PATH%\pathToScript\anotherBatch.bat" "%SOME_PATH%\pathToConfig\some.properties"
```

*Where `anotherBatch.bat` will use `%1` or `"%~1"` as the quoted argument and `%~1` as the unquoted argument.*

Comment: The problem is that anotherBactch.bat is blocking call that is why i used the start command to run the batch file in another cmd window. Is there away to call anotherBactch.bat asynchronously?

Comment: You need to properly explain to me how you believe a series of text strings inside a file with a `.bat` extension is `blocking` the `call` command which precedes it..