# Call multiple .bat from another .bat without waiting for one to finish

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

So, I want to make a script that will execute 2 .bat files and start some .exe files.

However, the .bat files are supposed to keep running.

I have something like this :

```
pushd tools\wamp64
start wampmanager.exe

pushd ..\..\server\login
call startLoginServer.bat

pushd ..\test
call startTestServer.bat

start "C:\DEV\P2\Test\client" P2.bin
```

The problem is that `call startLoginServer.bat` will not exit and therefore, I'm stucked here.

How can I run my 2 .bat files and let them keep running.
(Ideally, I want them to run in 2 different command prompt windows)

Also, there is probably a better way to handle relative path than using `pushd` if you can correct me on this.

Thanks

Comment: You could use `Start` instead of `Call`, if you're not wanting control to be passed back only when the batch file closes. If you take a look at the help usage, `Start /?` you could, if necessary, use the `/D` option to set the working directory. If you don't need to change the working directory you could `Start` the batch files directly, e.g. `Start ..\..\server\login\startLoginServer.bat` and `Start ..\test\startTestServer.bat`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
start "Wamp Manager" /B /D "%~dp0tools\wamp64" wampmanager.exe
start "Login Server" /B /D "%~dp0server\login" startLoginServer.bat
start "Test Server"  /B /D "%~dp0server\test"  startTestServer.bat
start "Text Client"  /B /D "%~dp0" "C:\DEV\P2\Test\client.exe" P2.bin
```

Run in a command prompt window `start /?` for help on this command explaining the options.

1. `"..."` ... title for new console window which is optional, but must be often specified on program to start is or must be enclosed in double quotes. The **START** command in last command line in batch file code in question interprets `C:\DEV\P2\Test\client` as window title. It is also possible to use an empty window title, i.e. `""` which is best if the started application is a Windows GUI application on which no console window is opened at all.
2. `/B`  ... run without opening a new window, i.e. in "background". This option can be omitted to see what the started applications and batch files output to console if the executables are not Windows GUI applications.
3. `/D "..."` or also `/D"..."` defines the directory to set first as current directory before running the command specified next. `%~dp0` references the directory of the batch file containing these commands. This path always ends with a backslash. Therefore no backslash must be added on concatenating the directory of the batch file with a file or folder name or path.

Run in a command prompt window `call /?` for help on `%~dp0` explaining how arguments of a batch file can be referenced from within a batch file.

See also the answer on [How to call a batch file that is one level up from the current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24725044/3074564) explaining in total four different methods to call or run a batch file from within a batch file.

Finally read also the Microsoft documentations about the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) and the structure [STARTUPINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) used by `cmd.exe` on every execution of an executable without or with usage of its internal command [start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start). The options of [start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) become more clear on having full knowledge about the kernel function and the structure used on Windows to run a program.