# Bash's "for" for windows

Tags: windows, cmd

How to can I to write this linux-like loop in the Windows 7 command line?

```
for docker_path in `ls | grep "docker$"`
do
    cd $docker_path
    mvn -B -f pom.xml clean deploy -Pdocker
    cd ..
done
```

I need found all *docker/ directory, exec there mvn-command and return into patern directory, but for Windows7 system.

Comment: Your bash code is broken. It should probably just be `for docker_path in *docker/; do ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows command line use:

```
for /D %I in (*docker) do @pushd "%I" & mvn.exe -B -f pom.xml clean deploy -Pdocker & popd
```

Use the following command line if `mvn` is not an executable, but a *.bat or *.cmd file:

```
for /D %I in (*docker) do @pushd "%I" & call mvn.bat -B -f pom.xml clean deploy -Pdocker & popd
```

Well, on command prompt it is not really necessary to use command **CALL** to run a batch file in a loop together with two other commands as done here.

The first command line for usage in a batch file:

```
@for /D %%I in (*docker) do @pushd "%%I" & mvn.exe -B -f pom.xml clean deploy -Pdocker & popd
```

In a batch file the loop variable `I` must be referenced with two percent signs instead of just one as on command prompt. The loop variable can be only a single character.

The second command line for usage in a batch file:

```
for /D %%I in (*docker) do @pushd "%%I" & call mvn.bat -B -f pom.xml clean deploy -Pdocker & popd
```

In a batch file it is necessary to use command **CALL** to  **call** another batch file and continue with next command respectively command line in current batch file after execution of the other batch file finished.

Windows command processor `cmd.exe` **continues** execution of current batch file on the other batch file on **not using** command **CALL** and exits batch file processing once the execution of other batch file finished without further processing command lines in current batch file.

See answer on [How to call a batch file that is one level up from the current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24725044/3074564) for details on the existing methods to run a batch file from within a batch file.

The single command line can be also coded with multiple lines:

```
@echo off
for /D %%I in (*docker) do (
    pushd "%%I"
    mvn.exe -B -f pom.xml clean deploy -Pdocker
    popd
)
```

And the same multi-line batch file solution in case of `mvn` is a batch file.

```
@echo off
for /D %%I in (*docker) do (
    pushd "%%I"
    call mvn.bat -B -f pom.xml clean deploy -Pdocker
    popd
)
```

Command **FOR** with option `/D` searches with wildcard pattern `*docker` for non hidden directories in current directory of which directory name ends with the string `docker`.

It is advisable on Windows to reference a file to execute with complete name of file, i.e. file name + file extension. This makes it clear for Windows command processor as well as every reader of the code if the executed file is an executable or a script file which makes a difference as it can be seen here.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`

See also:

- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564)
- [Microsoft's command-line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands)
- [SS64.com - A-Z index of the Windows CMD command line](https://ss64.com/nt/)