# How do I pass parameters to a running batch program by another one

Tags: batch-file, parameter-passing

example:

```
foo.bat :
@echo off
start bar.bat 2 3
set result=//somehow return the value
echo %result%
pause
exit

bar.bat :
@echo off
set int1=%1
set int2=%2
set /a result=%int1%+%int2%
//somehow send the result to the running foo.bat
exit
```

can someone give me an idea on how to do this. I can only think about writing a file and checking in a for loop if the file exists and what it contains. But this is way complicated in my opinion.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `call` to run a script from another script. Parent scripts can read the variables from child scripts as long as the child script doesn't use `setlocal`.

Comment: I use that but i would like to call the function from a separate file. If its possible. So i don't have to attach all the useful functions to the end of my current project. Or does the call function work from separate files as well?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you saying that you want foo.bat to call an intermediary script that calls bar.bat?

Comment: No. I want to call bar.bat script (which I know how to do) from foo.bat and I want to return the value somehow to foo.bat (which I don't know how to do)

Comment: Then instead of `start bar.bat 1 2`, use `call bar.bat 1 2` and when `%result%` gets set in bar.bar, foo.bat will be able to see it automatically because the two scripts share the same environment.

Comment: can you please write an example script for me. I kinda understand what you are saying but i don't want to spend an hour figuring it out completely. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Literally just change the line `start bar.bat 1 2` in foo.bat to `call bat.bat 1 2` and delete the `set result=//somehow return the value` line after that.

Comment: Thanks it worked. But you forgot that I needed to modify the exit to exit /b as well. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The batch file `foo.bat` must be written as follows:

```
@echo off
call "%~dp0bar.bat" 2 3
echo Result is: %result%
pause
```

The batch file `bar.bat` must be written as follows:

```
@echo off
set "int1=%~1"
set "int2=%~2"
set /A result=int1 + int2
```

The batch file `foo.bat` **calls** batch file `bar.bat` which means after processing of `bar.bat` the Windows command processor continues processing `foo.bat` with next command in that batch file after command **CALL**. Both batch files are processed by same `cmd.exe` and share the same list of environment variables.

That is not the case on using `start bar.bat` as this results in starting one more `cmd.exe` with its own list of environment variables for processing the batch file `bar.bat` being executed parallel by second instance of `cmd.exe` while first instance of `cmd.exe` continues processing `foo.bat` immediately after starting second `cmd.exe`.

The batch file `foo.bat` could be also written as:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
call :DoMath 2 3
echo Result is: %result%
echo(
pause
exit /B

:DoMath
set "int1=%~1"
set "int2=%~2"
set /A result=int1 + int2
goto :EOF
```

Everything below `DoMath` is now a subroutine which can be called multiple times from main code of `foo.bat`.

It is important that the batch files do not contain `exit` without parameter `/B` which results always in exiting `cmd.exe` processing the batch independent on calling hierarchy and independent on how `cmd.exe` was started before executing the batch file.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains also `%~dp0` ... drive and path of argument 0 which is the full path of the batch file always ending with a backslash.
- `echo /?`
- `exit /?`
- `goto /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `start /?` ... not used anymore

See also:

- [Debugging a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564).
- [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)
- [How to call a batch file that is one level up from the current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24725044/3074564)
- [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)
- [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative where the name of the resulting variable becomes defined in the main script during the call of the sub-script rather than by the sub-script itself:

**`foo.bat`:**

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem // Define name of variable to receive result here:
call "%~dp0bar.bat" RESULT 2 3
rem // Return result:
echo Result: %RESULT%
endlocal
exit /B
```

**`bar.bat`:**

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "INT1=%~2"
set "INT2=%~3"
set /A "SUM=INT1+INT2"
rem // Assign variable that has been defined during the call:
endlocal & set "%~1=%SUM%"
exit /B
```