# how capture GRADLE gradlew assembleDebug exit code in bash script

Tags: batch-file, gradle, gradlew

i have a simple batch script for **GRADLE** android as below

```
@ECHO ON
set DIR=path
set APP=%DIR%\app1
cd %APP%
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

next i want to check when **Gradlew** build is done, i can continue next command
something like

```
if(./gradlew assembleDebug) then echo "pass"
else echo "failed"
```

but i don't know how to implement in batch script

anyone know please tell me how to implement

thanks

Comment: I suppose this should work: `if errorlevel 1 (echo failed) else echo pass`

Comment: The first line should be `@echo off`. The second and third line can be removed and so the second line is `cd /D "path\app1"` whereby if `path` should be the path of the directory containing the batch file, it is possible to use `cd /D "%~dp0app1"` to change the current directory to the subdirectory `app1` of the batch file directory. The third command line depends on what `gradlew` is. There should be used `.\gradlew.exe assembleDebug` if the file `gradlew` has the file extension `.exe` which should be the case according [gradlew info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gradlew/info).

Comment: The Windows command processor `cmd.exe` processing a batch file waits for self-termination of a started executable on running it from within a batch file independent on being a Windows console or Windows GUI application. A Windows console application __usually__ exits with value `0` on success and a value __greater__ `0` if there an error occurred. But there are exceptions like [ROBOCOPY](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html). So please read the documentation respectively user guide of [The Gradle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html).

Comment: __Wait!__ It looks like the Gradle Wrapper is not an executable with file extension `.exe`, but a batch file with file extension `.bat`, i.e. the file name with extension is `gradlew.bat`. That makes a big difference as in this case must be used `call .\gradlew.bat assembleDebug` as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24725044/3074564). Otherwise the Windows command processor `cmd.exe` __continues__ the current batch file processing on `gradlew.bat` without ever coming back to your batch file for processing and executing the next command line.

Comment: The processing of a __called__ batch file can end also with exit code `0` for success and a different (greater) value than `0` for indicating an error condition. The exit code of a started executable or a called batch file is assigned by `cmd.exe` to its internal variable `ERRORLEVEL` and the command __IF__ can be used to continue further batch file processing depending on the value assigned currently to `ERRORLEVEL`. The help of __IF__ output on running `if /?` in a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) explains on first page how to evaluate `ERRORLEVEL` with correct syntax.

Comment: So the fourth command line can be `if errorlevel 1 (echo failed) else echo pass` as suggested by __Aacini__. For completeness read first [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564). Then you should have the knowledge that `call .\gradlew.bat assembleDebug && echo pass|| echo failed` could be also used to output a line with `pass` on success (exit code is `0`) or with `failed` on failure (exit code is not equal `0`).