# Why does npx end batch script?

Tags: node.js, batch-file, create-react-app

I am working on creating a simple setup script that I can use for most of my React applications. I want to be able to run the script and have it install all the npm packages I need as well as writing the boilerplate code for the configuration files. This is my current script:

```
@echo off

set /p userInput=Enter the folder name for your new React app: 
mkdir %userInput%
cd %userInput%

npx create-react-app . --template cra-template-pwa
npm install -D tailwindcss
npx tailwindcss init

echo.
echo Finished setting up React environment
pause
```

The script will run all the way up to the `npx create-react-app` line. When it gets to this line, it will run the command and create the React app, then die when CRA is finished. How can I make the script execute the rest of my commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be used the following improved batch file:

```
@echo off

:UserPrompt
set "userInput="
set /P "userInput=Enter the folder name for your new React app: "
if not defined userInput goto UserPrompt
set "userInput=%userInput:"=%"
if not defined userInput goto UserPrompt
mkdir "%userInput%" 2>nul
if not exist "%userInput%\" echo ERROR: Failed to create the directory: "%userInput%"& goto UserPrompt
pushd "%userInput%"

call npx.cmd create-react-app . --template cra-template-pwa
call npm.cmd install -D tailwindcss
call npx.cmd tailwindcss init

echo(
echo Finished setting up React environment
popd
cd /D "%userInput%" 2>nul
pause
```

`npx` and `npm` are batch files which must be called from within a batch file using the command **CALL**. See also: [How to call a batch file that is one level up from the current batch file directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24725044/3074564) This answer explains the four existing methods running a batch file from within a batch file and what are the differences.

See also: [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564) It explains in full details how to make a user prompt fail-safe and secure.

The user has the freedom to enter any string. There can be entered also:

```
"\\server\share\folder\Development & Test (!) 100%"
```

The batch file as posted works even for such a user input.

This batch file requires enabled command extensions and disabled delayed variable expansion. That is the Windows default execution environment on starting a command process for processing of a batch file.

There can be used `setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion` below the first line `@echo off` and `endlocal` at end of the batch file or above the command `pause`. But that would be counterproductive on `call npx.cmd tailwindcss init` defines or modifies environment variables which should still exist after processing of the batch file ended.

The *Windows Command Processor* does not change by Windows default the current directory to a folder on a network resource specified with its UNC path. This is the reason for using `pushd` and `popd`. The command `cd` at end tries finally nevertheless changing the current working directory to the directory as entered by the user in case of the user runs the batch file from within a command prompt window and expects that directory being finally the current directory after batch file execution.

- `call /?`
- `cd /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `mkdir /?` or `md /?`
- `pause /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also the DosTips forum topic: [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774)
The command `echo(` is the only possibility to output an empty line without any file system access.