# Batch file to run command

Tags: batch-file

I have this command to run kafka server which works fine in cmd but I want to batch file to run it in Windows. Please help

```
D:\Softwares\kafka_2.12-3.1.0>.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
```

Comment: ```@Call "D:\Softwares\kafka_2.12-3.1.0\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat" "D:\Softwares\kafka_2.12-3.1.0\config\server.properties"```, seems like a good place to start.

Comment: Works like a charm - Thanks @Compo

Answer (score 0):

This should work successfully (tested):

Edit:

```
@echo off
cd D:\Softwares\kafka_2.12-3.1.0\bin\windows
kafka-server-start.bat ..\..\config\server.properties
rem Do something here
exit
```

Or as Compo say, you said it work as a charm. Code:

```
@Call "D:\Softwares\kafka_2.12-3.1.0\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat" "D:\Softwares\kafka_2.12-3.1.0\config\server.properties"
```

Comment: I tried with this but it did not work   @echo off
start D:\Softwares\kafka_2.12-3.1.0.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
exit

Comment: What does it output?

Comment: The command line with `rem` is never reached and `exit` at end of a batch file is always just counterproductive. Please read my answer on [How to call a batch file that is one level up from the current batch file directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24725044/3074564) It explains the four existing methods for running a batch file from within a batch file and explains the differences. Compo posted in the comment the simple solution with using the command `call` to do what the name of the command states for.